# Can hot (un)plugging a SCART cable corrupt an SD card?

Tags: sd-card, composite-video

Currently I am using my Raspberry Pi as a media player with [Raspbmc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_based_on_XBMC#Raspbmc). It connects via [SCART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART) (using a composite-to-SCART cable) to my tv.

My tv has only one SCART-input, and I also want to connect my tv settop box. The solution was to tie the two SCART cables together with a rubber band and switch cables when I want to use Raspbmc or the tv. This solution works fine.

The only problem is that once every 1-2 weeks my SD card gets corrupted. I thought of a lot of reasons, and one is frequently disconnecting the SCART cable. I noticed that the big metal surrounding of the SCART connector is electronically charged when I accidently touch it. Maybe the sudden drop (or rise) in voltage can cause SD card corruption.

Could hot-plugging a SCART cable (and maybe sometimes accidently touching the connector) result in SD card corruption?

Comment: You had to buy a new sd card every 1-2 weeks? How many times did this occure?

Comment: Once I had to buy a new one, but normally re-installation of the OS was sufficient. That happened 6 or 7 times now I guess.

Comment: Could you post us a picture of the whole scart rig? The metal case should be GND and not have any voltage on it.

Comment: I use a composite to scart cable like this (http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/scart_to_rca_cable.jpg) for connecting the pi to my tv. My tv settop box is connect with a normal scart-to-scart cable. I just switch cables when I want to go from tv to Pi or vice versa.

Comment: does the raspi restart or hang or reboot when you play with cables?

Comment: No, the errors do not happen immediately when i play with the cables. I usually find the Pi freezed when i want to start a video.

Comment: Sounds like a small voltage be coming across the cable consistently. Usually this should be grounded out and not affect operation. It might be worth getting a scart switch box to help isolate things and spread the grounding load across more devices, as strictly the Pi isn't grounded on its own.

Comment: No, i didn't really solve it but since then i switched to HDMI and the problem persists so unplugging the scart cable isn't the problem. I'll add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a while I switched to HDMI and the problem still exists: once every few weeks the SD-card keeps getting corrupted. **Hot-plugging the scart cable cannot have caused the problem.**

My guess is that it's due to a faulty power source.

Answer (score 0):

'Anything' that causes a power 'glitch' can corrupt the SD - especially plugging and rfemoving USB devices (unless you have a powered Hub)

The 'best' way around this is to use a decent (5.2v 1.5A for original Pi A/B) power suply, a powered USB Hub and MINIMISE any 'writing' to the SD. NOTE that pulling the power plug 'counts' as a glitch ! (so if you need to force reset freqently, fit a reset button)

Having said that, my Pi (used a a digital photoframe) 'never' writes anythting to the SD and I've 'pulled' the power plug hundreds of times without corruption.